# Manejar dos sliders con un solo control. Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

pretendo manejar dos sliders de Bootstrap 4 con un solo controlador. He mirado en internet y [he encontrado una solución](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/w8EG9/7/) que me parece la más adecuada, pero cuando intento aplicarla no me funciona.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<div id="timeline" class="row timeline">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="timeline-wrapper h-100">
            <div id="carousel-timeline" class="the-timeline carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href=".the-timeline" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icomoon-triangle-left text-child-blue" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a href=".the-timeline" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icomoon-triangle-right text-child-blue" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div id="carousel-timeline-img" class="the-timeline carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="http://example.com/img-1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="http://example.com/img-2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="http://example.com/img-3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y:

```
$('#carousel-timeline, #carousel-timeline-img').carousel();
```

Pero no funciona, solamente es efectivo con el primero bloque, es decir con `#carousel-timeline`. ¿Qué anda mal aquí?

Gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 0):

finalmente lo solucioné con js:

```
$('#carousel-timeline').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event){
    var number  = event.to;
    $('#carousel-timeline-img').carousel(number);
});
```